# Why is self multiplying returning rediculously large number?

Tags: vue.js

I have following simple html and Vuejs code. When I ran this, I was surprised to find out that the output was displayed as following.

`3 times num = 4.6383976865880985e+49`

I was expecting to see 30.

If I make a variable and return that temporally variable, I do see the expected value of 30. What is going on here?

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p>3 times num = {{ mulBy3() }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    num: 10
  },
  methods: {
    mulBy3: function() {
      this.num = this.num * 3;
      return this.num;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't call methods in your template. Use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with computed property. But why is calling method not good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's a vital lesson in this!** Vue updates your page to reflect changes in your model. If rendering your page causes a change in your model (that causes Vue to re-render the page), then you have created an infinite loop - hence your very big number.

The moral of the story is that you don't know and shouldn't care when or how often your templates are rendered. You create the bindings such that your page reflects your model as you wish, then you leave Vue to take care of it. In practice, never call methods from a render function. Render functions should use data, injects, props, computed, perhaps watch: anything that's reactive. Methods should be used for responding to user activity and processing it back into the model.

Comment: Interesting... thats why creating temp variable and assigning it and returning it was not having issue... very interesting...

Answer (score 1):

You're running in to an infinite loop...

1. You call `mulBy3()` in your template
2. This mutates the `num` data property
3. This triggers a redraw
4. Goto #1

What you should do instead is use a computed property, eg

```js
computed: {
  mulBy3 () {
    return this.num * 3
  }
}
```

```html
<p>3 times num = {{ mulBy3 }}</p>
```

This will react to changes to `num`.

For more reasons why you should not call methods in your templates, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods